# Framework to run small independent tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, workflow

I have a requirement where I need to do following

1. Pull records from database with certain frequency(hourly, daily etc)
2. for each records make some API calls
3. for each record pdate the database with new info
4. do more stuff.....

The number of records can be huge. Is their a framework which can manage this workflow where each task/record can be on different stage during execution.

Comment: Have you looked at AWS Step Functions?

Comment: "each task/record can be on different stage during execution" sounds like decoupling. There are many ways how to achieve decoupling (e.g. using event driven architecture). There are tons of frameworks that can be recommended here, so this question can be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/). There are multiple production applications that rely on Cadence with requirements similar to yours.